# XSL to return XML of sharepoint 2010 list webpart

Tags: xslt, sharepoint-2010

I have a regular tasks list and I have to customize the way i display it sharepoint 2010.

In my main page I added a list webpart and it returned my the items ok... I need to develop a xsl to turn that xml my desired html, but i dont know what xml is comming...

what i need is a XSL that will make the webpart plot the raw XML.

Can anyone provide this XSL? i've searched a bunch of sites but it just dont work!

EDIT1: Ive checked this blog here "http://tomvangaever.be/blogv2/2011/07/custom-sharepoint-xsl-webpart/" but the return im getting is this error: "Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator." and Sharepoint designer only says that its wrong...

Comment: hummm you might have a point... the thing is that i dont know what XML im getting... and the output i want is the raw xml...

Comment: That's going to be difficult. XSLT is a declarative language, so it requires you to define rules by which your source XML should transform to your target XML. You say you have a "regular tasks list" - can we see what this looks like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the XSL to return the raw xml for a sharepoint list is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output version="1.0" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" method="xml" />  
  <xsl:template match="/">  
    <xmp>      
<xsl:copy-of select="*"/>  
    </xmp>  
  </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```